# CSS Sizing Height of Video Container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to size video containers height but for some reason, its height is unnecessarily big.

CSS:

```
.indexVideoContainer{

display:flex;
flex-direction: column;
background-color: #fff;
background-image: url(https://bellroy.imgix.net/cms_images/1259/background-texture-repeat.jpg?auto=format&fit=max);
width: 100%;


}
.indexVideoText{
    position: relative;
    font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px auto 20px auto;
    font-weight: 400;
    /* line-height: 32px; */
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
    max-width: 55%;
    top:50px;
}
.videoContainer{

    position:relative;
    padding-bottom:60.25%;
    padding-top:30px;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid black;

}
.videoContainer iframe{
    position:absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 35%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:70%;
    height:60%;

}
```

Codepen:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MZNgYa

Check the `.videoContainer` class. I added a border for a better demonstration. Its height is unnecessarily big. Expands too much for some reason. How do I make it shorter in a responsive way?

[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XAFU.png)

Edit:
I still have the problem guys.I have managed to fix it with some workaround but i guess i am missing something with video frame and flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="indexVideoText">
sometext
</div>
<div class="videoContainer">
<iframe title="hQ6TSIFM8I0" width="80%" height="80%" frameBorder="0" src="https://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/hQ6TSIFM8I0?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=hQ6TSIFM8I0&amp;origin=bellroy.com&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;version=3&amp;mute=1"></iframe>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.indexVideoText{
    position: relative;
    font-family: "PT Serif", serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px auto 20px auto;
    font-weight: 400;
    /* line-height: 32px; */
    color: #666;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto 40px auto;
    max-width: 55%;
    top:50px;
}
.videoContainer{
    position:relative;      
    height:500px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px solid black;
  background-color:red;
  padding-top:20px;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
 iframe{
    position:absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:70%;

}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the answer.When i applied that yes container is small but video inside youtube video frame is also small...http://prntscr.com/m9dzol

Comment: Oh that is because i did not give a bigger value to the height

just change height:200 to height:500px

Comment: thank you again.one last question is what about puting some extra space on and below container ? http://prntscr.com/m9e3xm

Comment: Yes mam, You just need to go the iframe tag and decrease the height and width to 80% , because right now it is 100% once you change it to 80% then you cN add more padding or margin for more space , I have editied the answer

Comment: actually i meant expanding the videoContainer http://prntscr.com/m9eaxc

Comment: Check the picture i just posted

Comment: oh but it looks perfect in mine , Can you edit your codenpen with your current codes, So i can take a look at it ?

Comment: its same with the one you sent.

Comment: Check my answer i have updated it , If this does'nt work , I will surely help you out tomorrow , Cuz its 1am in my place so i gotta sleep. Thanks for your time